# Access Control In Airpal : shiro_static_users.ini

Tags: hive, presto

I am not able to access airpal through username and password that i  provides in  shiro_static_users.ini file , After the changes done i had compile the code and start the airpal server :

Without giving any username and password i am able to access the airpal server.
I have pm as a database in hive and want to give permission to raj user.

My ini file:

```
authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter
shiro.loginUrl = /login
authc.successUrl = /app

allGroup = com.airbnb.shiro.UserGroup
allGroup.groups = all
allGroup.permissions = access, read:*:*, write:*:*
allGroup.defaultConnector = hive
allGroup.defaultSchema = default
allGroup.timeout = 40m
allGroup.accessLevel = User

allGroup1 = com.airbnb.shiro.UserGroup
allGroup1.groups = pm
allGroup1.permissions = access, read:*:*, write:*:*
allGroup1.defaultConnector = hive
allGroup1.defaultSchema = pm
allGroup1.timeout = 40m
allGroup1.accessLevel = User



cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
sessionListener = com.airbnb.shiro.SessionListenerLogger

allowAllFilter = com.airbnb.shiro.filter.AllowAllFilter
allowAllFilter.groups = $allGroup ,$allGroup1
allowAllFilter.loginUrl = /login

securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager

[users]
test = test, all
raj = raj, pm

[roles]
all = *
pm = *

[urls]
/login = authc
/logout = logout
/app = authc, perms["access"]
/api/** = authc, perms["access"]
```

Comment: I have changed shiro:
  iniConfigs: ["classpath:shiro_static_users.ini"] in reference.yml file